# Why table require two clicks when it has more than 5 row?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I have the problem. I have a page with dropdown menu that contain customers name and if customer name is selected appear table with customer configuration. 
[image]

Customer can choose row in the table use one click on left mouse button:
[image]

When table has more than 5 rows it's style is changed (There is restriction display no more than five rows).
[image]
And if we press left mouse button in the first time on any field of page, table style is changed (also dropdown menu is unfocused):
[image]
And it's necessary press left button of the mouse in the second time for select configuration. It is happened only when table has more than five rows. (Table is built by jquery).

Code:

```
function changeCustomerName(customerName) {
        getConfigurationsForSpecifiedCustomer(customerName);
    }

function createTableForConfiguration(data){
    fillTable(data);
    $('#configurationTable').show();
}

function fillTable(data){
    $('#tableBody').empty();
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        $('#tableBody').append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' +
            item.id +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            item.name +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
        )
    });
}

function getConfigurationsForSpecifiedCustomer(customerName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/getConfigurationsForSpecifiedCustomer",
        data: JSON.stringify(customerName),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            createTableForConfiguration(response);
        },
        error: function(e){
            // alert('Error from getConfigurationsForSpecifiedCustomer' + e);
            console.log('Error from getConfigurationsForSpecifiedCustomer' + e);
            $('#configurationTable').hide();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#secondTable').on("click", '#tableBody tr', function(){
        var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
        $("#tableBody tr").removeClass("highlight");
        if(!selected)
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $("[name='configuration']").val($(this).context.children[0].innerText);
    });
});
```

html:

```
 <div id="table" class="scroll">
                <table id="secondTable" class ="tableBorder">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none">id</th>
                        <th>Configuration Name</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Product Version</th>
                        <th>Solution Build</th>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>GP Code</th>
                        <th>Oracle DB Version</th>
                        <th>Configuration Version</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableBody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

style:

```
    body {
    font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

table.tableBorder {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.tableBorder th, table.tableBorder td {
    padding: 4px 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.scroll{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.highlight { background-color: grey; }
```

response of ajax call:
[image]
What a reason can be?

Comment: pl share ajax response here

Comment: I just try use this solution without ajax and in work correctly. One second and I add ajax response. Ajax response represent by itself array of pojo class.

Comment: Bhumi Shah, I added ajax response. See picture above.

Comment: I don't know how ajax call affected on filling table, but it does that. I try use sync instead of async, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can type of object in response array affected on html?

Comment: I passed List<String[]> from controller to html page and it works correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary increase width in scroll class.